# How can I create a conditional converter based on the source value instead of its type using ModelMapper?

Tags: java, mapping, modelmapper

I'm trying to map an entity to a DTO using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/). The problem comes when a @JoinColumn is not loaded(lazy load). ModelMapper tries to access the lazy load entity's properties and then a LazyInitializationException is thrown.

I already have an strategy to solve that but I could not find a single ModelMapper feature which does what I need.

**Here is what I need to do:**
For each not loaded entity, I'll create a new target object using my factory. If the object is loaded, then the default mapping must be applied.

The following example is a ModelMapper feature that would fit exactly with my needs if it wan't by the fact that it does not provide the source(provides only the source type):

```
public static class MyConverter implements ConditionalConverter<Object, Object> {

    private EntityManager em;

    public MyConverter(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public MatchResult match(Class<?> sourceType, Class<?> destinationType) {
        Object source = null; // I need the source instead of its type.
        PersistenceUnitUtil persistenceUnitUtil = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();
        return persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(source) ? MatchResult.NONE : MatchResult.FULL;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(MappingContext<Object, Object> context) {
        return LazyEntityProxyFactory.factory(context.getSource(), context.getDestinationType()); // Creates the target object
    }
}
```

Do you guys of any ModelMapper feature which provides what I need. Or maybe a hack?

*Obs: I've looked into ModelMapper's code and noticed that when [ConditionalConverter.match](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/spi/ConditionalConverter.html#match-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) is called the context already exists and therefore it possesses the source. What if ModelMapper had also a ConditionalContextConverter interface which passes the context in the match method? Just an idea.

Answer (score -1):

I just found what I needed! The secret is to check the properties from the parent entity. After that I was able to leverage from the default mapping and also use my own factory if needed.

Here's my ConditionalConverter:

```
public static class MyConverter implements ConditionalConverter<Object, Object> {

    private EntityManager em;

    public MyConverter(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public MatchResult match(Class<?> sourceType, Class<?> destinationType) {
        return MatchResult.FULL;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(MappingContext<Object, Object> context) {
        Object source = context.getSource();
        Object destination = context.getMappingEngine().createDestination(context);

        try {
            Field[] sourceFields = context.getSourceType().getDeclaredFields();
            Field[] destinationFields = context.getDestinationType().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field sourceField : sourceFields) {
                sourceField.setAccessible(true);
                for (Field destinationField : destinationFields) {
                    destinationField.setAccessible(true);
                    if (sourceField.getName().equals(destinationField.getName())) {
                        Object sourceFieldValue = sourceField.get(source);

                        PersistenceUnitUtil persistenceUnitUtil = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();
                        if (persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(sourceFieldValue)) {
                            MappingContext<?, ?> myContext = context.create(sourceFieldValue, destinationField.getType());
                            Object destinationValue = context.getMappingEngine().map(myContext);
                            destinationField.set(destination, destinationValue);
                        } else {
                            // Here is your factory call;
                            destinationField.set(destination, SomeFactory.factory(sourceFieldValue, destinationField.getType()));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return destination;
    }
}
```